# What is the difference between additive and multiplicative attention?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, attention-mechanism

This paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03999) implements additive addition. I think the attention module used in this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.08318) is an example of multiplicative attention, but I am not entirely sure. Can anyone please elaborate on this matter?

Also, the first paper mentions additive attention is more computationally expensive, but I am having trouble understanding how. Any insight on this would be highly appreciated. Thank you.